# Maximize windows just like Windows on OS X

Tags: macos, mac, screen, shortcut

I have owned a MacBook Pro for a year, however at work I use a Windows laptop. Since I really like the functionality to maximize a windows by just pushing it to the top of the screen, I would like to have that on my Macbook too.

I am using Spectacle to assign shortcuts like "windows" to maximize a window, which works well and I recommend it.

However, is there any application to maximize a window like the way you can do it on a Windows laptop/pc, just by pushing the window to the top of the screen?

Note: I mean maximize window, not fullscreen.

Comment: It's worth noting that this used to be how it worked in OS X, too - the all-knowing apple decided that the users clearly wanted fullscreen instead with a recent OS X update. I'm stuck on 10.7 so I still have the old functionality, at least. Also, holding 'option' (alt) while clicking the fullscreen button should do it.

Comment: @Wyatt8740: at least the current fullscreen behaviour is more consistent. I'd heard hundreds of people calling the green button the "maximise" button instead.

Comment: @BenS As long as consistent means bloody annoying and change for the sake of change, I'll agree. I called the green button maximise because that's what it does for 99% of programs on old versions of OSX.

Comment: In Mac OS Sierra you can also double click on the window corner to automatically expand it to maximum size, I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Kubuntuer82, that was the exact functionality I was looking for. This is similar functionality to Windows. Double click on window border when the resize mouse icon appears.

Comment: @Ligemer You are welcome, and because of your feedback I decided to add it as an actual answer, since it also does not depend on any 3rd party software.

Comment: This needs tying to the almost duplicate [How to maximise a window to fill up screen in Mavericks?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115895/how-to-maximise-a-window-to-fill-up-screen-in-mavericks/420692#420692)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai) app which does exactly what You need. You can download a trial and check it.

[image]

There's also [Better Snap Tool](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bettersnaptool/id417375580) from the same developer on the MacAppStore which does only window snapping.

Comment: They also have a simple version just for snapping called 'Better snap tool' although it breaks some of my apps and crashes occasionally.

Answer (score 37):

Hold <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>option ⌥</kbd> and click the green maximise button on the top left part of the window.

[image]

*NOTE: not every OSX application is eligible for maximize (example: maximizing the Finder doesn't work)*

Comment: This is the only answer that correctly address the question and without any third party sowftware

Comment: However it doesn't work.

Comment: @OleksandrShpota unless they changed something during latest OSX updates, it should. I will publish a gif this evening, to make it easier to understand.

Comment: I have OS X 10.13.6. If I do what you proposed it just zooms a window a bit, but doesn't make it fill the screen. Try testing it on Finder window.

Comment: @OleksandrShpota ok thanks for the information. I will verify. Normally it should fill the screen in width and height.

Comment: @OleksandrShpota you were right, the combination changed. It's opt + alt + shift and click. I've also updated the answer with a gif.

Comment: It still doesn't work. Tested on Finder window. I guess it depends on the application and on the content inside the window. For instance, both combinations: the old one and the new one successfully maximize Chrome window

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will add it to the answer

Comment: sometimes just using *alt* + *shift* with click on green maximize button did the job for me

Comment: @JonathanArgentiero your answer still mentions Option + Command, which only zooms vertically. You need to include Shift in order to maximise the window across the entire screen.

Comment: @MarcelloRomani I've updated the answer

Comment: @JonathanArgentiero I still see only Shift + Option. How did you update it?

Comment: On Mac OS 10.14.5 option+click works on the apps I tested

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as I'm sure most people who come here are looking for a simple answer that works and not having to install and purchase 3rd party tools unnecessarily.

Comment: I don't this the `Shift` does anything extra. I think `Option` + `Click` does the same as `Shift` + `Option` + `Click` (as per @akaasjager's answer below)

Comment: I dont see any difference between this (the answer currently say "option+shift + click the green Button") and just option + click on the green button. without the addition "shift". 

And yes - I need and want it *especiually* for the finder, becaue this is the main app that behaves strangely.

Comment: This does not work at all on the latest OS X.

Comment: This option works in Catalina, but another option that apparently has been around since Sierra is to double-click the corner of the window while the resize arrow icon is showing. That works on my Mac as well.

Comment: What is the reason for some software not showing this?

Answer (score 16):

**A workaround without any 3rd-party software:**

If you double click on any **window corner** (when the resize pointer appears) while holding the <kbd>⌥</kbd> (option) key, this will maximize the window.

Alternatively, you can also double click on the **window corner** (when the resize pointer appears) to automatically expand that corner to maximum size. Therefore, if you double click on the **top-left** corner and then on the **bottom-right** corner, the window will expand completely, that is it gets maximized.

**Update:** I have recently realized that for many apps, in my experience around 60%/70% of them, you can also just double click on the **title bar** and the window gets maximized as well. For the apps where this does not work (e.g. iTunes or some apps which have no title bar) you can still double click on opposite window corners as explained above.

Comment: After using this for a while, I think it is better functionality than Windows IMO. Much nicer experience to be able to expand the side or to top corner of screen. Definitely more `Apple Like` and gives the user more control.

Comment: @Ligemer Better functionality than Windows? You've got to be kidding. MacOS has the absolute worst window management functionality of any desktop OS. Hence, this huge thread of people trying to figure out how to make it more like Windows.

Comment: Actually @Ligemer is right, being able to maximize only horizontally or only vertically provides more freedom than Windows, where you are forced to maximize on both directions. The only issue with MacOS is that people _don't know_ these things, and they have to learn them as secret "tricks". Perhaps Apple people should find a way to _let people know_ about these "tricks", without forcing them to do very hard searches on the web to find them.

Comment: I agree that it should be more obvious in the UX - and the maximize feature was missing for literally decades from Mac. Also the inconsistency between apps is not good. However, SHIFT+OPTION while hovering over the green maxmize button gives resize options, and my Finder now maximizes on double-click of title bar after using those options, where before it didn't - I can't quite figure that out yet. Would be nice to have a clear preferences panel for this behavior.

Comment: This is the one that works and requires no additional software. What a ridiculous UI.

Comment: Thanks for the trick with double click the corner of the window with pressed the Option key! This was the only way how to get back top part of the window with title bar that stuck ouside the screen after disconnecting from external monitor. I tried all the tricks I know from Linux or Window OS but MacOS is very ehm special and unfriendly in many ways.

Comment: There is no need to press the Option key.

Comment: @MichaelLiquori I am now on Monterey and I confirm that you still need to press the Option key if you want to maximize the window by double clicking on just one corner. If you want to do it without the Option key, you will need to double click on two opposite corners (e.g. top left and bottom right, or top right and bottom left).

Comment: @GeekInDisguise Windows can maximize vertically by double-clicking on the top or bottom window border. At least as far back as Windows 7. You aren't forced to maximize on both directions.

Answer (score 14):

There is a simple, but annoying standard way: hold <kbd>alt/opt</kbd> when clicking the green button on the top bar. It will **change into a plus** instead of the double arrow, and after clicking your window will be maximized.

Comment: Yes but not on the whole screen, just the height.

Comment: That's strange. On my Yosemite it does maximize both width and height, with the curious exception of Safari on large external monitors.

Comment: This actually invokes the zoom command, which is not the same as maximise. Zoom is supposed to enlarge the window such that it makes best use of the available screen space for its content. What this means is left to the application to decide. Safari won't enlarge horizontally if the webpage already fits in the window without a horizontal scroll bar. Some applications do just maximise the window.

Comment: I have not enough point to answer but I found an interested way: hold alt key and double click on window edge to maximize horizontal or vertical, on window corner to maximize both!

Comment: alt/opt does work with some apps, but not all. Especially not with the finder.

Yelliver's solution works! without "alt", double clicking on any corner only maximizes in the direction of the two borders that match in the clicked corner(click top right to maximze the window from where it is to the top and the right, leavin left and bittoim as is, for example) - but adding the "alt" it maximizes everywhere! Thanks @yelliver

Answer (score 12):

If you are still looking for an alternative way, have a look at [Spectacle](https://www.spectacleapp.com/).

- You can select from the menu or use a keyboard shortcut.
- There are many resize options but your requirement is "Fullscreen ⌥⌘F"
- It is not like OS X full screen but Windows like maximum.

[image]

Comment: "I am using Spectacle to assign shortcuts like "windows" to maximize a window" @Thijs Kempers already mentioned about it.

Comment: @Mateus: but the original question said to be still looking for this functionality, so it obviously wasn't known that this is possible with spectacle.

Comment: Spectacle is no longer maintained. I'm the developer of [Rectangle](https://rectangleapp.com), which is based on Spectacle. If I understand the original question properly, I think the ask is to be able to drag the window to the top of the screen to maximize. Spectacle did not have this behavior, but Rectangle does.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> and double-click a window's corner, when the resize pointer appears.

Thanks to Kubuntuer82 and their answer for giving me the idea of trying out their technique while holding <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>. It worked for me on macOS Catelina :D

Comment: Only this worked without installing third-party app. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same issue and found that Rectangle is a perfect free and open source solution: https://rectangleapp.com/

Comment: Perfect, exactly what OP asked for (and I was looking for as well).

Answer (score 2):

There is an app called [Cinch](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/cinch/) that mimics the Windows behavior you've described.  You can run it in demo mode, indefinitely, to see it does what you want before purchasing it.

> Cinch gives you simple, mouse-driven window management by defining the
>   left, right, and top edges of your screen as 'hot zones'. Drag a
>   window until the mouse cursor enters one of these zones then drop the
>   window to have it cinch into place. Cinching to the left or right
>   edges of the screen will resize the window to fill exactly half the
>   screen, allowing you to easily compare two windows side-by-side
>   (splitscreen). Cinching to the top edge of the screen will resize the
>   window to fill the entire screen (fullscreen). Dragging a window away
>   from its cinched position will restore the window to its original
>   size.

Answer (score 1):

On El Captan, and maybe earlier, you can **double click** the top bar to make the window larger. It's similar to the Windows double click but some apps don't fill the whole screen. Not exactly click and drag like you were asking, but this way you don't need to install any third party apps.

Comment: doesn't work with all apps - especially not with finder.

Comment: Seems to do the same thing as the Zoom/+ mentioned in other answers above where it just expands to fill the height but not the width of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I use SizeUp for window management in OS X. I've used it for about 4 years now. SizeUp allows you to use keyboard shortcuts to move windows to different quadrants or halves of the screen. There is also a shortcut for maximizing the window. I used to miss the Windows gestures for window management, but once I got used to the keyboard shortcuts, I came to prefer OS X + SizeUp over the "drag to the top to maximize" gesture from Windows 7.

http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/

Answer (score 0):

Option-click the green traffic light button on the title bar

Answer (score -1):

You can do that using [Split Screen Ultimate](https://www.splitscreenapp.com).

When you press Control key and move the window to the top section of the screen, it will maximize the window - the way you want.

[image]

[image]

Disclosure: I own this app.

Answer (score -3):

I'd also like to suggest you Moom: https://manytricks.com/moom/