# How to make double click on titlebar maximize a window to fill up screen?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, settings

I hide my dock. How do I acheive this: **double click on titlebar to maximize a window to fill up screen?**

Please pay attention to two red rectangles (not fill up the screen though I double click on titlebar) as shown below a screenshot of the entire screen.

[image]

This post [How to maximise a window to fill up screen in Mavericks?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115895/how-to-maximise-a-window-to-fill-up-screen-in-mavericks) proposes to use [SizeUp](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/sizeup/) (PS: it is not free?) by assigning a new shortcut. Is it still possible to use double click?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to maximise a window to fill up screen in Mavericks?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115895/how-to-maximise-a-window-to-fill-up-screen-in-mavericks) While the question is from Mavericks, the best suggestions (BetterTouchTool and SizeUp) remain the same.

Comment: @tubedogg, I refer to this post in my updated question.

Comment: In your post you said "_Please pay attention to two red rectangles as shown below a screenshot of the entire screen._", so exactly why are we supposed to be paying attention to the red rectangles?

Comment: @user3439894, thx, just updated my question. The two red rectangles indicate that the app does not fill up the screen though I double click on titlebar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BetterSnapTool](https://www.boastr.net/bettersnaptool/) has the option that you're requesting. (The drop-down has many options including maximize.) You can also change the behavior of the green zoom button to do this as well.

[image: BetterSnapTool preferences]

Comment: It is not free:-(

Comment: @sparkandshine No, but if you purchase a license for BetterTouchTool, you get a free license for BetterSnapTool (and most of its functionality has been integrated into BTT anyway), and BTT has a pay-what-you-want model that starts at $4.50.